# Highlighting and save the selected text from WebView?

Tags: android, webview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am working on Android 4.0.3 . I am trying to select the text from the WebView and saving it as a string . I have tried this Code:

```
public void SelectText(){  
try{  
           KeyEvent shiftPressEvent =   
           new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,       
           KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT, 0, 0);  
           shiftPressEvent.dispatch(mWebView);  

}catch(Exception e){  
  throw new AssertionError(e);  
}
```

But it doesnot work . In Android 4 there is already an inbuilt menu for selecting text but how this menu could be overridden ??

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses a javascript interface to pass touches to the page and effectively cut Android's native selection out of the equation. This has been tested from 2.2 to 4.0.3.

Look at this [Github](https://github.com/btate/BTAndroidWebViewSelection) Project .